# how to write date on each new line?

Tags: python, loops, file, date, datetime

i have a problem with the correct writing of the date to the new file. I would like each line in the new file to start with the date, I don't know how to write the loop correctly to do it, so far I manage to save only 1 line of the date in the new file.

In general, the task is to read the text from the file then save it to a new file but that each line is with the date.

```
 filename = datetime.datetime.now()

    data = pipe.recv()
    data_new = data
    pipe.send(data_new)
    file1 = open('new_results.txt', 'w')
    file1.write(filename.strftime("%Y_%m_%d-%H_%M_%S: "))
    file1.writelines(data)
    file1.close()
```

I mean this line, how to loop it correctly so that each line displays the date.

```
 file1.write(filename.strftime("%Y_%m_%d-%H_%M_%S: "))
```

Comment: e.g. using `file1.writelines([prefix + line for line in data])` with `prefix` being whatever string you want to have at the beginning of each line.

Comment: And as a nit-pick: `filename` as a variable name for a datetime object is pretty misleading if you ask me. Your *file name* is actually `'new_results.txt'`.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example using as much of your code as possible.

```
import datetime

filename = datetime.datetime.now()                            # Not sure why you called date filename, but so be it
data = ["first line", "second line", "third line"]            # Made up data

with open('new_results.txt', 'w') as file1:                    # Python recommends using file context manager rather than direct open/close
    for line in data:                                          # Loop over the data lines
        file1.write(filename.strftime("%Y_%m_%d-%H_%M_%S: "))  # Writes the date
        file1.write(line + '\n')                               # write a line of data after date, followed by carriage return
```

**Output in File new_results.txt**

```
2021_05_27-07_10_19: first line
2021_05_27-07_10_19: second line
2021_05_27-07_10_19: third line
```

Comment: @MrFuppes--correct--I didn't properly edit his code.